# How to export 2 commands to one text file cmd

Tags: windows, command-line

I'd like to ask if there is a way how to export 2 outputs of 2 (or more) commands to the very same text file

Example

```
dsget user "cn=John Smith,ou=users,ou=us,dc=americas,dc=com" -memberof
```

and

```
dsget user "cn=Stuart Little,ou=users,ou=us,dc=americas,dc=com" -memberof
```

What I'd like to get is list of groups of both users to the same text file.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something along the lines of

dsget user "cn=John Smith,ou=users,ou=us,dc=americas,dc=com" -memberof >> %~DP0Example.txt 
dsget user "cn=Stuart Little,ou=users,ou=us,dc=americas,dc=com" -memberof >> %~DP0Example.txt

will append to a text file